# how to just show the markers which are in the teritory of United state

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, jquery-plugins

I use google map and just for representation of my work as a demo I need to throw some markers in the map I use the following code :

```
  var southWest = bounds.getSouthWest();
            var northEast = bounds.getNorthEast();
            var lngSpan = northEast.lng() - southWest.lng();
            var latSpan = northEast.lat() - southWest.lat();
                 tmplan=new google.maps.LatLng(
                            southWest.lat() + latSpan * Math.random(),
                            southWest.lng() + lngSpan * Math.random());
```

Everything is good but I want those markers to be shown that are in the territory of United state Does anyone has any suggestion?

Comment: What do you mean by the "territory of the United States"?  The continental US?  This is just for test/demo?  How many points?

Comment: Thanks for answering , By US I mean country of US. Yes this is just for demo but the customers expect to see just markers located in United state. I want 1000 markers.

Comment: This is gonna be connected to database but for now that I do not have data in database I have to do this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First create a polygon of the US

```
var polygonUs = [
    new google.maps.LatLng(25.774252, -80.190262),
    new google.maps.LatLng(18.466465, -66.118292),
    new google.maps.LatLng(32.321384, -64.75737)
];
```

check if tmplan is inside polygon, if yes show it.

```
if (google.maps.geometry.poly.containsLocation(tmplan, polygonUs)) {
    marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        map: map,
        position: tmplan
    });
}
```